# Toolstripmenu add item

Tags: .net, vb.net, toolstrip

I know how to add a item(checkbox) to a toolstrip dynamically, but I want to add a checkbox which is exists in a form. I've tried using the code

```
Dim chkboxhost As ToolStripControlHost
chkboxhost = New ToolStripControlHost(CheckBox1)
toolStrip1.Items.Add(chkboxhost)
```

but this makes the already existing checkbox, go to the top left of screen and when the toolstrip is click it appears. So I want to add the checkbox to the menu, without going to top left corner, any ideas ?

Comment: Usually this is done with a `ToolStripMenuItem`, setting `CheckOnClick = true`.  Does that not fit your needs?

Comment: Oh I see what you are asking - you have one checkbox you want displayed in two places.  This can't be done - each checkbox has its own position.  What you will have to do is create two checkboxes and set up each one to update each others' `Checked` status, in its `CheckedChanged` event.  Or it can be done more easily if you are using databinding:  just bind them both to the same property and you are done, they will both update each other automatically *(or more correctly, the BindingSource will update both of them)*

Answer (score 0):

BlueRaja's response is the answer, you could do it several ways, here's two:

Firstly:

```
Private Sub ToolStripButton1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ToolStripButton1.Click
    ToolStripButton2.Checked = ToolStripButton1.Checked
    'Do whatever you want with your buttons
End Sub

Private Sub ToolStripButton2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ToolStripButton2.Click
    ToolStripButton1.Checked = ToolStripButton2.Checked
    'Do whatever you want with your buttons
End Sub
```

Another approach:

```
Private Sub ToolStripButton1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ToolStripButton1.Click
    'Do whatever you want with your buttons
End Sub

Private Sub ToolStripButton2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ToolStripButton2.Click
    'Do whatever you want with your buttons
End Sub

Private Sub ToolStripButton1_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ToolStripButton1.CheckedChanged
    ToolStripButton2.Checked = ToolStripButton1.Checked
End Sub  

Private Sub ToolStripButton2_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ToolStripButton2.CheckedChanged
    ToolStripButton1.Checked = ToolStripButton2.Checked
End Sub
```

I prefer the first one obviously.